# How can I represent edges for a graph in terms of a list?

Tags: c, list, graph

How can we represent a graph as a list of edges?

Answer (score 6):

There's three common ways of doing this:

1. Adjacency matrix: A V * V table of edge weights, where the ith column on the jth row is the weight of the edge between vertices i and j. If there is no edge, infinity is often used (or you can use some sentinel value, like -1).
2. Adjacency lists: An array of V linked lists. Each ith list in the array is a list of edges leaving the ith vertice.
3. Edge list: Simply a list of tuples (u, v) of edges.

Different ones are suitable for different purposes. Personally I find the adjacency lists to be the most useful, but if you have a very dense graph then an adjacency matrix can improvement performance and memory usage.

Comment: thank you. but in C programming, how can we initialize a list of edges using the edge list as mentioned in 3. say we have this list of edges (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(1,2),(1,3) and we have to initialize it in our main program

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna store exactly edges, use matrix of weights: `int** M;`, where `M[i][t]` is the length of the edge between i and t vertices.

If your graph edges have weight of 1, you could store graph in adjacency matrix, where `M[i][t]` equals to:

- **0** if there is no edges between i and t vertices
- **1** if there is edge from i to t
- **alpha** if i == t and there is a loop in i (or t) vertex

If you requre structure, critical for memory usage, store your graph in the linked list, where each vertex has structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
  int N;
  Vertex* next;
};
```

So you would have array of Vertex structures, each containing pointer to the next it is connected to. For example, here is some linked-list-graph:

- 1 -> 3 -> 4
- 2 -> 5
- 3 -> 4
- 4 -> 3
- 5 -> 2

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to implement the representation yourself, as a learning exercise or to have more control, consider using a library such as [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) which is a C library for representing and manipulating graphs.  Or go one abstraction level down - build adjacency lists or edge lists yourself, but use the list-building capabilities of [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) rather than rolling your own.